# EditText do Android está deprecated

Tags: android

O que devo fazer se a classe `EditText` do Android está *deprecated*? Tem outro comando que possa substituir?

Comment: Pode postar um print da mensagem? O EditText não está deprecated

Comment: Também fiquei curioso com isso.